# React-Joyride tutorial start and stop with Context?

Tags: reactjs, npm, zurb-joyride

I am making a `react-joyride` tutorial for my `create-react-app`.

My goal is to build a tutorial to start and stop periodically, as the user progresses through the site. This means the tutorial will turn on and off with certain user behavior (changing pages, launching a new module, etc)

**Issue:** How to integrate: **steps** <> **Joyride** <> **component state** across multiple pages and components?

I considered (4) different approaches:

1. Having one single **master** 'steps' JSON that is loaded and managed in context and passed down to pages
2. Having multiple **individual** 'steps' JSON files in each page and component.
3. Having one single `<Joyride />` component at a global level that receives a single JSON 'steps' file
4. Having multiple `<Joyride />`components on each page / component with a local 'steps' files

I've tried all four approaches, but still not able to make joyride work fluidly across multiple pages.

Any ideas/suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I’ve got basic joyride working, but it only works on one page. When I try to add to another page, it doesn’t work.

Comment: Since it's been over a year, If you have solved the issue,  please let us know , what approach did you end up taking.

Comment: In the end I couldn't make it work and abandoned 'react-joyride'